# fill entire area of tabhost tab with listview programmatically

Tags: basic4android

Is it possible to directly fill a tabhost tab with a listview directly, or should the listview be placed on a panel first. Also, how/what sytax do I use to get the content on the tab to be 100%x and 100%y programmatically?

So in other words - a Tab with a listview on it, but the listview takes up 100%x of the tab, and all of the open space for y (except for the tabs)

Currently each tab is an empty layout file. I want to place content on the layout strictly programmatically if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above code will add a ListView to a TabHost, the ListView will fill the tab:

```
Dim tb As TabHost
tb.Initialize("")
Dim lv As ListView
lv.Initialize("")
For i = 0 To 10
    lv.AddSingleLine("Item #" & i)
Next
tb.AddTab2("Tab1", lv)
activity.AddView(tb, 0, 0, 300dip, 300dip)
```

Comment: Thanks - I had found a solution overnight - but this helps streamline things as well.